# org.apache.commons.io,version=[2.6,3) -- Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Hi I have included commons-io with version 2.4 & checked my M2 inventory which has only 2.4 commons.io but I have a bundle error which is referencing 2.6,3 which doesn't exist, I tried cleaning up my M2 & reinstall, created new AEM Instance, checked out different code base which has 2.4 commons.io but the bundle still reports error. please help

error : org.apache.commons.io,version=[2.6,3) -- Cannot be resolved

Comment: Add the dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

Comment: I already had this dependency for lang3, but i still get this error

Comment: i have added following dependencies   <Import-Package>com.adobe.cq.sightly;version="2.5.3",com.day.cq.commons;version="5.7.6",javax.inject;version="0.0.0",*</Import-Package>      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
   </dependency>   <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>